# Add a "Migrate to xx SE site" option in the Off-Topic section for flagging questions

Tags: feature-request, flags

When I see a question that is off topic, I'll flag it.

[image]

But, should we add an option like:

> o belongs to (dropdown list of SE sites)
>
> Questions about (bla bla bla) should be asked here instead of Askubuntu.

So that Moderators can migrate off-topic questions to corresponding sites like Unix and Linux, since most off-topic questions got closed instead of being migrated.

Comment: If you add a comment about I think this might be a better fit on, they might do it.  There's even a pro-forma comment for it.  I'm pretty sure this has been asked before.